# How to use Getx state management without using Getview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

My friends and I are doing a project with Flutter.He doens't use any state management method and I want to use Getx.So how can i use Getx without using Getview class so that our both codes work in a harmony?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbLBk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
class MyView extends StatelessWidget {
  // you can also put it here
  final controller = Get.put(MyController());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // you can put it here
   final controller = Get.put(MyController());
    return Text(
      controller.myText.value,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    );
  }
}
```

either ways try to play with it

Comment: Is this code in main.dart or in other file?What should I do to main.dart?

Comment: this is for different dart in main u should call the GetmaterialApp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Getx controllers by keeping StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget, just initialize your controller with `GetBuilder`

```
class TestView extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<TestController>(
      init: TestController(),
      builder: (controller) => Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```